# Infinispan 11.x - 12.x XML Configuration

Tags: xml, jboss, config, infinispan, hot-rod

I was guessing if there's a specific section on the infinispan's XML config file where I can specify the following entities:

- HotRod configuration
- JBoss configuration

I'm trying to find anything related in the official documentation but wasn't able. I'm passing from Infinispan 9.x to 11.x or 12.x, and I see there's a huge difference in the XML config file.

Thank you.

Edit 1:
[I'd like to reproduce this part in the new config XML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdmwl.png)

Comment: are you upgrading the Infinispan server? can you share your config? If it is the server, I would recommend starting from the default config (infinispan.xml) and tune from there.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply! Check Edit 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Endpoints documentation](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/server/server.html#endpoint_connectors). I believe it has everything you need.

Be advised that the new Infinispan server uses a single port (11222 by default) to handle REST and Hot Rod requests.

You have the [Schema description here](https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/12.0/configdocs/infinispan-server-12.0.html). Search for "endpoints".

If you still have trouble updating your configuration, feel free to comment here or check the [Zulip Chat](https://infinispan.zulipchat.com/#).